# how to get list of missing header columns of csv file?

Tags: c#, exception, header, csvhelper

I have a functionality to upload the CSV file. And in any case
I am getting one of the column exception while uploading the csv file. I am using CsvHelper to perform related csv operations.
And the problem is how we can get the list of missing header columns of csv file (while uploading the csv file) inside 'CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException'.?
I am using C#.

For ex:
If I have 10 columns inside my Model, so while uploading the csv file it should matches the csv column with the model columns.
And I wanted to find out missing columns of csv file as compare to model.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing header columns"? Columns you expect but that are not in the CSV file? Maybe a small example can make this clearer.

Comment: Author of the library appears fairly active on their GIT. You might want to check there as well. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/discussions

Comment: @KlausGütter, updated the question with example.

Comment: Can't you simply do `modelColumns.Except(csv.HeaderRecord).Any()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HeaderValidated` in the `CsvConfiguration` to get a list of the missing headers.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HeaderValidated = args => 
        {
            foreach (var header in args.InvalidHeaders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Missing header: {header.Names[0]}");
            }
        }
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id\n1"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    { 
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();       
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```